# Is there a keyboard shortcut to open a registered server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Getting to the `Registered Servers` pane is easy enough with `Ctrl-Alt-G`.

Navigating thorugh the tree is easy enough with arrow keys.

Once the desired instance is found, is there a keyboard action that will open it in `Object Explorer`? If so, what is it? If not, can it be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the "right-click" key on your keyboard, you can use it, followed by <kbd>E</kbd>.

It's often called the "Menu" key, so <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>.

If you don't have that key, you can use <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd> instead. Thus: <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>.